# Convert CSV elements into a single Array using Azure Logic Apps

Tags: arrays, azure, csv, azure-logic-apps

I have a csv file which has the following sample values 
ReportId,ReportName
1,Poy
2,Boy
3,Soy

I want this to be converted into a single array like 
[ReportId,ReportName,1,Poy,2,Boy,3,Soy] 
using logic apps.
Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

You could refer to my below flow. Init a csv data, then split with expression `split(outputs('Compose'),'\n')`, you need to go to code view to edit the expression, or it would be `split(outputs('Compose'),'\\n')`.

[image]

[image]

Then do the loop action to get the single data. The `for each 2` input is `split(item(),',')`. Then append the current item to the array.

[image]

Here is my result.

[image]