# Convert CSV file as array in logic apps

Tags: azure-logic-apps, azure-logic-app-standard

I want to read CSV file as array in logic apps. I didn't find any documents related to it. Any help on this would be appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on your question here are few arounds that we can try below either way for 2 different outputs.

**READ EACH OBJECT CSV FILE AS ARRAY OBJECT:**
We can use split and add the output of the `compose` connector into Array by adding 'Initialise Variable' Connector and for converting each word into array variable we need to add `for each` connector inside another `for each` connector to iterate the items inside the CSV file then with a split variable inside the inner `for each` connector having `split(item(),',')` expression.

**READ EACH ROW IN CSV FILE AS AN ARRAY:**
We can use Plumsail's Parse CSV connector in order to convert each CSV row as an array considering headers in the CSV file.

Here are the screenshots for your reference

[image]

[image]

- Expression in `compose` connector

  ```
  split(body('Get_blob_content_(V2)'),'\n')
  ```
- Expression in `For each 2` connector

  ```
  split(item(),',')
  ```

**Note:** Make sure you go to your code view and change the expression in your split from
`split(body('Get_blob_content_(V2)'),'\\n')` to `split(body('Get_blob_content_(V2)'),'\n')` as when we are writing the expression for this it first takes '\n' as string and adds another "" to the expression.

Here is the code view of my logic app

```
{
    "definition": {
        "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/providers/Microsoft.Logic/schemas/2016-06-01/workflowdefinition.json#",
        "actions": {
            "Compose": {
                "inputs": "@split(body('Get_blob_content_(V2)'),'\n')",
                "runAfter": {
                    "Get_blob_content_(V2)": [
                        "Succeeded"
                    ]
                },
                "type": "Compose"
            },
            "Compose_2": {
                "inputs": "@variables('array1')",
                "runAfter": {
                    "For_each": [
                        "Succeeded"
                    ]
                },
                "type": "Compose"
            },
            "For_each": {
                "actions": {
                    "For_each_2": {
                        "actions": {
                            "Append_to_array_variable": {
                                "inputs": {
                                    "name": "array1",
                                    "value": "@items('For_each_2')"
                                },
                                "runAfter": {},
                                "type": "AppendToArrayVariable"
                            }
                        },
                        "foreach": "@split(item(),',')",
                        "runAfter": {},
                        "type": "Foreach"
                    }
                },
                "foreach": "@outputs('Compose')",
                "runAfter": {
                    "Initialize_variable": [
                        "Succeeded"
                    ]
                },
                "type": "Foreach"
            },
            "Get_blob_content_(V2)": {
                "inputs": {
                    "host": {
                        "connection": {
                            "name": "@parameters('$connections')['azureblob_1']['connectionId']"
                        }
                    },
                    "method": "get",
                    "path": "/v2/datasets/@{encodeURIComponent(encodeURIComponent('AccountNameFromSettings'))}/files/@{encodeURIComponent(encodeURIComponent('JTJmY29udGFpbmVyMjQlMmZkYXRhLWFydGljbGUuY3N2'))}/content",
                    "queries": {
                        "inferContentType": true
                    }
                },
                "metadata": {
                    "JTJmY29udGFpbmVyMjQlMmZkYXRhLWFydGljbGUuY3N2": "/container24/data-article.csv"
                },
                "runAfter": {},
                "type": "ApiConnection"
            },
            "Initialize_variable": {
                "inputs": {
                    "variables": [
                        {
                            "name": "array1",
                            "type": "array",
                            "value": "@outputs('Compose')"
                        }
                    ]
                },
                "runAfter": {
                    "Compose": [
                        "Succeeded"
                    ]
                },
                "type": "InitializeVariable"
            },
            "Parse_CSV": {
                "inputs": {
                    "body": {
                        "content": "@{base64(body('Get_blob_content_(V2)'))}",
                        "headers": "url,user_id,token_id,username,password"
                    },
                    "host": {
                        "connection": {
                            "name": "@parameters('$connections')['plumsail']['connectionId']"
                        }
                    },
                    "method": "post",
                    "path": "/flow/v1/Documents/jobs/ParseCsv"
                },
                "runAfter": {
                    "Compose": [
                        "Succeeded"
                    ]
                },
                "type": "ApiConnection"
            }
        },
        "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
        "outputs": {},
        "parameters": {
            "$connections": {
                "defaultValue": {},
                "type": "Object"
            }
        },
        "triggers": {
            "manual": {
                "inputs": {
                    "schema": {}
                },
                "kind": "Http",
                "type": "Request"
            }
        }
    },
    "parameters": {
        "$connections": {
            "value": {
                "azureblob_1": {
                    "connectionId": "/subscriptions/<Your subscription>/resourceGroups<Your resourec group >/providers/Microsoft.Web/connections/azureblob-1",
                    "connectionName": "azureblob-1",
                    "id": "/subscriptions/<Your subscription>/providers/Microsoft.Web/locations/northcentralus/managedApis/azureblob"
                },
                "plumsail": {
                    "connectionId": "/subscriptions/<Your subscription>/resourceGroups/<Your resourec group >/providers/Microsoft.Web/connections/plumsail",
                    "connectionName": "plumsail",
                    "id": "/subscriptions/<Your subscription>/providers/Microsoft.Web/locations/northcentralus/managedApis/plumsail"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**REFERENCES:**
[Convert CSV elements into a single Array using Azure Logic Apps - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61782287/convert-csv-elements-into-a-single-array-using-azure-logic-apps)